# VS2010, F5 - Builds but doesn't run (WPF)

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

We just converted a WPF application to VS2010. When I press F5, the solution builds but then does not run.

If I do CNTL+F5 (start without debugging) the app runs just fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
jeff

Comment: Let's start obvious, and work our way out.  Do you get any runtime errors?  Do other (converted and/or from scratch) solutions run with F5?

Comment: @WonkotheSane, I'm experiencing the same issue after renewing the solution file. No errors.

Comment: @Shimmy - I would suggest closing VS, deleting the suo file, and restarting VS.  If that doesn't work, write up a new problem (or keep Googling - I did not do that).

Comment: I followed that and it didn't work. I had to restart the whole machine.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what it was.  Deleted .suo file, closed VS2010, restarted machine and it was ok.

Answer (score 0):

you might be using a different keyboard scheme than the standard C# (or for some reason, the shortcut to run has changed).  check the shortcuts in `Tools->Options`, under `Environment->Keyboard`

Comment: No. I'm trying it out with the mouse too and clicking the toolbar icon as well as selecting the option in the menus.

Comment: I've done this too: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /resetsettings

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this be caused by a lack of an App.xaml file or something incorrect in the startup there. Make sure you have an App.xaml file and that it has something like this:

```
<Application x:Class="Query.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Note the StartupUri, ensure you have one and it's valid, that or you have a Startup line that points to a valid method int he App.xaml.cs

Answer (score -2):

The project or the solution file may be corrupted. In that case, create a new one and re-add all the files and references.