# C# can't start debugging application in IDE

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I have C# application built in VS2010. Recently I changed something in project properties and now I have strange problem:

- I can't start debugging of my application (F5). When I press F5 project compiles but then nothing happens. Even if I put some dummy code to my program.cs main function ie MessageBox.Show() it's not executed.
- I can build app using "Build solution", it compiles and executes with no problems

In project properties following options are enabled:
- Define debug consant
- Define trace constant
- Advanced bulid settings / Debug info - full

What should I change to be able to debug my app from IDE?

Comment: Are you in a multi-project solution? Are you sure that you properly choose the "Start-up project"?

Comment: Rebuild or cleaning didnt help? or worst case restart app/OS ?

Comment: check the Configuration Manager under `Build`. does it look ok in there?

Comment: Also check `Tools > Properties > Environment > Keyboard` and under "Press shortcut keys" make sure that F5 maps to "Debug.Start"

Comment: is it possible to run the program via the green arrow in the Visual Studio toolbar?

Comment: Is it a winforms application?

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting .suo file. Make backup first!

Here is similar thread:
[VS2010, F5 - Builds but doesn't run (WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866022/vs2010-f5-builds-but-doesnt-run-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown and restart VS :) It's happened to me a few times before.